# How does DNS work in Raspbian?

Tags: networking, dns, systemd-networkd, dhcpcd

How does DNS work on a Raspberry Pi (a recent version of Raspbian)?

From what I understand:

- When I write a program and want to connect to `somedomain.com`, I don't specify what DNS server to use. I use a library function built into the language that asks the kernel to resolve the domain
- The kernel ALWAYS uses `/etc/resolv.conf`
- For some reason, in modern version of Linux, this is auto-generated by `resolvconf`

  - Why? What problem is `resolvconf` trying to solve? What was wrong with having DHCP clients like `dhcpcd` or `systemd-networkd` modify `/etc/resolv.conf` directly?
- `resolvconf` doesn't run as a systemd service, so the dhcp client service needs to detect, and trigger `resolveconf` when a DHCP server supplies us with a new DNS server to use

  - What info does the dhcp client (`dhcpcd`) provide `resolvconf`? Just the new DNS servers it learned about from the DHCP server?
- Where does `systemd-resolved` come in?

  - It's not enabled by default
  - If you enable it, does it work with `resolveconf`, or replace it?
- Where does `systemd-networkd` come in?

  - It's not enabled by default
  - If you enable it (and disable `dhcpcd`), and specify a static DNS server in `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network` using the `DNS` parameter, does it inform `resolvconf` of this? Does it try to modify `/etc/resolv.conf` directly? Does it expect `systemd-resolved` to be running?

On the surface, it seems like things were a lot simpler when it was just a single file and none of these tools had to interact with each other.

Comment: You are asking for a tutorial on Linux networking.

Comment: @Milliways Linux has dozens of different network packages that all do different things. Some work together. Others compete. This is a question about a very specific part of Linux networking (client-side DNS), a very specific tool (`resolvconf`), and about a specific implementation of it (on Raspbian). Even using the exact same tools, other distributions probably do things a bit differently. I want to know how the RPi does it, hence raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. This question can definitely be answered in the short answer format of SE.

Comment: There is no better place to look for a tutorial on Linux than SE! Also, I have the same question since I recognised that my DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` is still my LAN's router although I have applied an `openvpn` config (from surfshark) that should forward all traffic through the tunnel. It seems DNS is not forwarded, and I wonder how to set it (and also inquired surfshark about it).